# What exactly is the "information" that dapper caches?

Tags: c#, caching, dapper

On Dapper's documentation found [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#limitations-and-caveats) it states:

> **Limitations and caveats**
> ***Dapper caches information about every query it runs***, this allow it to materialize objects quickly and process parameters quickly. The current implementation caches this information in a ConcurrentDictionary object.

What exactly does this mean?
Ex: Is it caching returned data, or the query itself, or bits of both?

It also says that "**this [cached] data is never flushed**".  How does this effect the "cached information" if the design schema of the table(s) you are querying is changed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know has each query you issue an `Identity`, depending on the sql query, its command type and its parameters. The cache is a dictionary with concurrent access.

```
Dictionary<Identity, CacheInfo> _queryCache
```

This `CacheInfo` object contains the `IDataReader` and `IDBCommand` functions and some control counters which limit the cached amount.

Since no server-side (database schema etc.) are cached, it actually doesn't have any influence.

Edit: Thats how the Identity class looks like used for caching.

```
private Identity(string sql, CommandType? commandType, string connectionString, Type type, Type parametersType, Type[] otherTypes, int gridIndex)
        {
            this.sql = sql;
            this.commandType = commandType;
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
            this.type = type;
            this.parametersType = parametersType;
            this.gridIndex = gridIndex;
            unchecked
            {
                hashCode = 17; // we *know* we are using this in a dictionary, so pre-compute this
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + commandType.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + gridIndex.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + (sql == null ? 0 : sql.GetHashCode());
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + (type == null ? 0 : type.GetHashCode());
                if (otherTypes != null)
                {
                    foreach (var t in otherTypes)
                    {
                        hashCode = hashCode * 23 + (t == null ? 0 : t.GetHashCode());
                    }
                }
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + (connectionString == null ? 0 : connectionString.GetHashCode());
                hashCode = hashCode * 23 + (parametersType == null ? 0 : parametersType.GetHashCode());
            }
        }
```

And here's the CacheInfo

```
class CacheInfo

        {
            public Func<IDataReader, object> Deserializer { get; set; }
            public Func<IDataReader, object>[] OtherDeserializers { get; set; }
            public Action<IDbCommand, object> ParamReader { get; set; }
            private int hitCount;
            public int GetHitCount() { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref hitCount, 0, 0); }
            public void RecordHit() { Interlocked.Increment(ref hitCount); }
        }
```

And finally the container of the cache.

```
static readonly System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<Identity, CacheInfo> _queryCache = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<Identity, CacheInfo>();
```

Have a look at the source code, its very well written and easy to follow / debug. Just drag the file into your project.

Answer (score -1):

If need reset the cache, you can use next code

```
private static void ClearQueryCache()
    {
        var cacheDictionary = typeof(SqlMapper)
            .GetField("_queryCache", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null);

        cacheDictionary.GetType()
            .GetMethod("Clear", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Invoke(cacheDictionary, null);
    }
```